# Writing a basic shader for large input files

Tags: opengl-es, ios

I started writing a shader for my iOS app and instead of starting from scratch i used this tutorial here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial

I wrote an import function, first to import wavefront .obj models. My problem is that with I can't handle larger inputs (with a simple cube it was working). I realized that the indices array is an array of GLubyte values, which is unsigned char, so as a result i cant have more than 256 indexes. I modified it to GLuint, but then only get a blank screen.

What else needs to me modified?

p.s.: the source can be downloaded from here: http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/HelloOpenGL.zip

Answer (score 1):

[glDrawElements](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) accepts only GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT. Using GL_UNSIGNED_INT should give you an error. Are you checking errors with [glGetError](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) function?

Comment: not yet, but thanks for pointing that out. I'm still new in opengl ES. do you know if there's any already made shader with the bare basics that can handle more vertices/indices?

Comment: Shader doesn't care how many vertices you are submitting to it. Code will look the same if you are draw int 3, 10, 100 or 10000 vertices.